# Prevent over-wrapped line draw when using DrawRect or DrawBorder

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

[image]

```
Private Sub pancontrols_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles pancontrols.Paint

    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Yellow)
    Dim borderWidth As Integer = 1
    Dim theColor As Color = Color.Gray
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, theColor, borderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, theColor, borderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, theColor, borderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, theColor, borderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub
```

the code is like the above.

When I resize, especially resize to incrase the width, the painted lines are remaining.

Even though I cleared the e.Graphics with solid color, the problem still exist.

Is there any simple way to prevent that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try invalidating on the resize event with this in your panel's constructor:

```
Public Sub New()
  Me.DoubleBuffered = True
  Me.ResizeRedraw = True
End Sub
```